Apache tomcat stops when user logs out (Linux)
So there's this particular server where Apache Tomcat behaves differently.
The service was started by executing ./startup.sh from its directory.
On other servers, Tomcat keeps running even if the user logs out.
But for this particular server, when the user logs out, Tomcat stops as well.
What could be the reason for the behavior difference?
The OS is RHEL 8.

Do you have any special reason not to run tomcat via systemd (as service/daemon)?

"The service was started by executing ./startup.sh from its directory." - Yeah, that's totally unacceptable. Don't do that. Use a proper service runner (systemd is the modern go-to, but there are others).

@RomeoNinov I can partially explain that: many "integrators" leave scripts and instruct their clients to start and stop their systems like that, and won't support if someone does things any other way. I fighting at my current place of work for every such case which would be possible to automate, but they're doing it manually for years because of the support. For example, every month one night several people do table partitioning in some Oracle database: some control services that depend on that database (to not behave erratically), some do actual rotation, and that happens for 10+ years...

Systemd by default stops all leftover user processes when that user logs out from all sessions (as tracked in loginctl). Some Linux distributions disable this feature, others keep it enabled. It can also be disabled for all users via logind.conf(5) on each system, or individual users can opt out by setting the 'linger' flag (documented in the same logind.conf manual page).
The idea behind this feature is that manually-run shell scripts are not a good service management system, and one should start services through a service manager that's able to monitor and restart them – e.g. through systemd itself, by writing an /etc/systemd/system/my-tomcat.service that runs the necessary processes.

Are you trying to say it'll kill my tmux/screen sessions? Or they are other level citizens, and leaving tmux running is considered having a valid session?

@NikitaKipriyanov: Generally it would, yes ("Note that setting KillUserProcesses=yes will break tools like screen(1) and tmux(1),"), although – as I just noticed written in the manual – despite the parameter name, the killing is scoped to the session that was just closed, and not the user overall; so if you're running a modern tmux which spawns each pane's contents in a separate systemd --user scope unit, then those will still survive as long as the user overall remains logged in (since the lifetime of systemd --user is tied to the refcount of the user's all sessions).

Either way, this is off by default on the distro I use and I've had no desire to try enabling it to see what exactly happens.


What could be the reason for the behavior difference?

That depends on how the "other servers" are configured.
Unix, and Linux, maintains a lineage of processes - the OS knows which process spawned a child. When a parent process (your shell) exits, it sends a HUP signal to its children. You can see this parent/child relationship visually using the pstree command.
I am guessing that you do not want Tomcat to exit when you logout. Without delving too deeply into the underlying mechanisms, you need to tell the OS to do that.
Until a few years ago, the conventional way to do that would be a script in /etc/init.d (with links from the runlevel directories in /etc/rc.d) taking a single argument with value "start" or "stop" (although they may also implement "restart", "reload" and potentially other behaviours). This is (part of) the SysV init mechanism. Most Linux distributions now use systemd which uses a configuration file. This uses a configuration file, and for things you maintain yourself (rather than packaged software) the file should be deployed to /etc/systemd/system. By conventional, the files for service daemons have a .service extension.
If you search the internet you will find examples of SysV init scripts and systemd unit files for Tomcat. You may find that your Tomcat package already includes such file(s) but tese have not been deployed.
Note that systemd has some backward compatibility and will still start services configured under the SysV init system.

Said backwards compatibility with init.d is likely to go away within the next 2-3 systemd releases. (Though of course that won't affect OP's RHEL 8 for a few more years, and distros might still continue maintaining it locally.)

You can use nohup for this:
nohup ./startup.sh &


This is certainly not a recommended practice. Considering @grawity answer up there, it might even not work at all in some systems.
